# matrix equality given the equality of products?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

For two symmetric p.s.d matrices $M$ and $N$ (of size $n\times n$), for any two vectors $x$ and $y$ (of size $n\times 1$), if I have: 
$$
x^TMy = x^TNy, \forall x, y
$$
can I say $M=N$?

Eventually, I want to know that, if
$$
(x^TMx)^{-1}x^TMy = (x^TNx)^{-1}x^TNy, \forall x, y
$$
can I say $M=N$?

Comment: If you choose $y = e_i$, this picks out the $i$th column. If you pick $x = e_j$, this picks out the $j$th row.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Sorry I don't understand your comment very well. I'm curious about the case when the equality holds for any $x$ and $y$, I don't understand how picking some particular $x$ or $y$ helps.

Comment: If it holds for any $x,y$ it holds for these particular $x,y$. This lets you see certain relationships. If you know those things are equal for any $x,y$, picking $e_i$ and $e_j$ as described picks out the $i,j$ entry, and those are equal. Entry by entry, this implies they have to be equal.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it holds for any $x,y$, it holds for some particular $x,y$. In particular, if $y = e_i$ and $x = e_j$, then this choice picks out the $(i,j)$ entry. If the equations are to hold, this says the $(i,j)$ entries are equal, and so working entry by entry, we see that all entries are equal.